# Add clarification on job message responses

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs, jobs-messages

I've just got a job message, and now I have two options:

[image]

I wasn't sure if I'll be prompted to add my own message after clicking one of the buttons.

What happened is that the action was taken; the recruiter received my response, and only then I was prompted to enter a custom action.

I think that one of the two should be done:

- Add a clarification that when clicking on one of the buttons the recruiter will be notified, and *only then* we'll be able to enter a message, or
- Enable us to add a custom text after clicking, that will be sent *along* with the response, and not after it as a separate response

Comment: Agree that some clarification would be helpful here. We don't have immediate plans to work on this, but will update this post when I have more info.

Comment: I agree that this UX is currently unacceptable.  I received an inquiry about a job I would normally be interested in.  However, I have too many other things going on in my life to consider changing jobs right now.  I don't want to flatly say 'not interested', but I _also_ don't want the recruiter to waste her time following up with me.  Ideally, I'd reply with something like "I can't make a move right now, but I hope you'll keep me in mind in the future."  With the current UI, I have no idea which button, if any, will enable me to draft a custom response.